# Android- Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0

Tags: android, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle, android-room

I've been trying to add room library dependency to my project. but I keep seeing this error:

```
Error:Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0.
```

I've searched a lot to solve the problem but I couldn't

**build.gradle file of the Project**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.reminder"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 25
        buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
  // Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

**root build.gradle file**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You don't need both `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com'}` and `google()` - they're the same repo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add like this:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}
```

and:

```
dependencies {

    // Room
    implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:1.0.0"
    annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:1.0.0"
}
```

EDIT:

If you are using Offline Mode of Gradle, then disable the offline mode and sync gradle again. You can turn on Offline Mode after successful sync.

Offline Mode:

> File > Settings > From left Pane: Build, Execution, Deployment > Gradle
>
> Change "Offline work" to enable/disable Offline Mode

[image]